# Trigger : update column based on value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-update

We have a table that contains a status column, and associated to that is a column to track when the status changed values.

As an example, we have a status of 'Off' and a status of 'Found Off' along with associated columns, `DateOff` and `DateFoundOff`. I'm trying to create a trigger to update these date columns when the status changes.

It seems rather straightforward to me, but what is occurring is when the `Status` changes the associated date column updates correctly, but the other date column becomes null. So if I change Status = 'Off' DateOff has the correct date but DateFoundOff becomes null and visa versa.

I created two triggers - first one is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [GIS].[UPDATE_FOUNDOFF]
ON [GIS].[METEROUTAGEPOINTS]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    IF (UPDATE (OutageStatus))
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE [gis].[METEROUTAGEPOINTS] 
        SET DateFoundOff = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        FROM gis.METEROUTAGEPOINTS mop 
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.ConObject = mop.ConObject
        WHERE i.OutageStatus = 'Found Off'
    END
```

And the second

```
ALTER TRIGGER [GIS].[UPDATE_DATES]
ON  [GIS].[METEROUTAGEPOINTS]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    IF (UPDATE (OutageStatus))
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        UPDATE [gis].[METEROUTAGEPOINTS] 
        SET DateOff = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        FROM gis.METEROUTAGEPOINTS mop 
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.ConObject = mop.ConObject
        WHERE i.OutageStatus = 'Off'
    END
```

I simply do not understand how one trigger is changing the value of the Date column to null that is not associated to the current status value.

Thanks.

Edit:  The issue was found to not be with trigger but instead be with how the tool being used to edit the data was holding onto something.  Not sure I understand why, but by changing the edit workflow the problem was resolved.  Marked answer as correct based on it giving a far better way to write the trigger

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: And note that IF UPDATE does not do what you expect. If you ONLY want to do something when the value actually changes, you need to check the before (deleted) version against the after (inserted) version.

Comment: I suggest setting up a dbfiddle because as it stands its not reproducible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I am OP I  found the problem was not associated to the issue presented in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your update statements change `DateFoundOff` or `DateOff` to null. Something else must be going on.

However I would improve your trigger as follows:

1. Only use a single trigger, every trigger has overhead, having one trigger with one update statement will run faster than 2.
2. You aren't actually checking that the status has changed, all you are checking is that the update included that column. Add a check against the `deleted` table actually checks whether the value changed.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [GIS].[UPDATE_FOUNDOFF]
ON [GIS].[METEROUTAGEPOINTS]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- Avoid doing any processing if no rows are updated
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Inserted) RETURN;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(OutageStatus) BEGIN
        UPDATE [gis].[METEROUTAGEPOINTS] SET
            DateFoundOff = CASE WHEN i.OutageStatus = 'Found Off' AND d.OutageStatus <> 'Found Off' THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ELSE DateFoundOff END
            , DateOff = CASE WHEN i.OutageStatus = 'Off' AND d.OutageStatus <> 'Off' THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ELSE DateOff END
        FROM gis.METEROUTAGEPOINTS mop 
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.ConObject = mop.ConObject
        INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON d.ConObject = mop.ConObject;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: according to the microsoft specs, shouldn't you throw in the IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0)
RETURN; at the start of this trigger? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @dale-k I did try to include the join on the d table, although left that out of my posted sample.  I will setup as the single statement, I had originally tried an approach with a single statement, but based on your sample was probably not correct.  I broke into multiple triggers thinking maybe that was causing my issue.  I will look into anything else that could be configured in the database to cause this

Comment: I've actually gone over to `IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted))` in my triggers, because of the risk of putting any statement before `ROWCOUNT`

Comment: No, `ROWCOUNT` at the start of the trigger always takes the enclosing scope, the previous trigger fired for the same statement is ignored https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3dd3bf78cdb83daeb55310d1425e26fe

Comment: @Charlieface OK thats good, so you do it the way you do, just to avoid the potential for making a mistake?

Comment: ..@@rowcount is not reliable when MERGEing

Comment: @lptr nice! Thanks!

Comment: @DaleK After additional review the issue was related to the tool being used to edit and how it was holding onto something with the row.  Not sure I understand that specifics but after changing around the process everything works as expected.  Thanks for all the advice on the proper and most effective way to setup the trigger